# Using python mechanize to log in websites

Tags: web-scraping

I am using python mechanize to log in the social website https://www.pinterest.com/login/. I run into an error:

> HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt

Here are my simple codes.

```
import urllib
import re
import mechanize
browser=mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("https://www.pinterest.com/login/")
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser.form['username_or_email']='xxx@example.com'
browser.form['password']='xxx'
browser.submit()
print browser
```

What is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I add the code "browser.set_handle_robots(False)". Now the problem is that it leads me to an error webpage: http://www.pinterest.com/csrf_error/

Comment: Hi, have you managed to log into pinterest in the end?